# Create an array of strings to be sent as argument to a function that accepts a string

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I am trying to figure out how to declare and use an array of strings. I see everywhere that the suggestion is to use array of type variant. Why can't I create an array of only strings?

I have a functions that receives a string as an argument and I need to call this function 6 times with 6 different strings. This seems like a situation where the best would be to use an array of strings and loop over it and each time call the function with the right string. How am I declaring such array and access it?
If I declare an array of Variant I get a type mismatch error, as my functions expects a string.

Thanks

To be more specific, this is what I did:

```
dim strings() as variant
dim i as integer
dim res as integer
strings = Array ("string1", "string2", "string3")

For i = LBound(strings) To UBound(strings)
   res = MyFunction( strings(i))
Next


MyFunctions(str as string) as integer
'do something
end function
```

This gets a compiler error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to the above suggestion:

It's not a problem to call the same function 6 times, but if you're always processing an array of strings it also wouldn't hurt to pass an array in.

```
Sub subTest()

    Dim arrStrings() As String

    For i = 1 To 6
        ReDim Preserve arrStrings(1 To i)       '   Extend the array - 'preserve' retains the old values too
        arrStrings(i) = "this is string " & i
    Next i

    For Each strValue In arrStrings
        Debug.Print (strValue)                  '   Just so we see each string
    Next strValue

    Debug.Print (fncDoSomething(arrStrings))    '   Passing string array as parameter

End Sub
                                                '   Example function which counts how many characters are in your array.
Function fncDoSomething(ByRef strings() As String) As Integer    '   ByRef is important when passing an array.

    Dim intCharCount As Integer
    Dim strValue As Variant
    intCharCount = 0

    For Each strValue In strings
        intCharCount = intCharCount + Len(strValue)
    Next strValue

    fncDoSomething = intCharCount

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a few syntax errors, you are passing a variant type by reference to a function that expects a string.

This can be overcome by forcing VBA to cast the expression as a string:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim strings() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim res As Integer
strings = Array("string1", "string2", "string3")

For i = LBound(strings) To UBound(strings)
   res = MyFunction((strings(i)))
Next

End Sub

Function MyFunction(str As String) As Integer
Debug.Print str
End Function
```

by placing an extra set of parenthesis around the parameter that is being passed.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/byref-argument-type-mismatch